# grep extract specific pattern from a large file of 190GB

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, grep

I need to extract the email addresses from a large 190GB flat file (only error log) that I cut into a 5mb files. (with 152,353,216 lines)

The grep command works well, but the memory quickly becomes saturated and I end up getting errors.

The content of the files is not formatted, so I have to use regexp.

```
grep -r -E -h -o "\b(pattern)\b" /dir/* > outs.txt
```

How to process files one by one?

Comment: What errors are you getting? I'm curious about why the memory consumption would grow, and what makes you think the problem is related to memory.

Comment: @TomFenech grep eventually no longer find a pattern after 20,000 analyzed files, and displays only the name of the files. Processing is launched on a NAS in RAID10.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your data, your disk performance and your CPU, you may get on better with **GNU Parallel**. If you use the `--pipepart` option it will also split your 190GB file up for you without creating temporary files.

So, I created a 5GB file with 100000000 lines using Perl like this:

```
perl -E 'for($i=0;$i<100000000;$i++){say "Line $i,field2,field3,junk,junk,junk",int rand 1000000}' > BigBoy.txt
```

The first 3 lines look like this:

```
Line 0,field2,field3,junk,junk,junk514649
Line 1,field2,field3,junk,junk,junk257773
Line 2,field2,field3,junk,junk,junk203414
```

I then timed a `grep` at 58 seconds on that file that produced 88 lines of output:

```
time grep "junk426888$" BigBoy.txt
```

I then timed **GNU Parallel** at 11 seconds for the same output:

```
time parallel -a BigBoy.txt --pipepart --block -1 grep "junk426888$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs` to execute your grep command on each file separately (rather than on all the files)

```
ls -1 /dir/ | xargs -n 1 -I '{}' grep -r -E -h -o "\b(pattern)\b" '{}' > outs.txt
```

The `-n 1` flag instructs xargs to run one process on each file.

The `-I '{}'` argument instructs xargs to replace '{}' with the name of the file.

In other words, if `/dir` contains `file1`, `file2`, `...`, it executes successively

```
grep -r -E -h -o "\b(pattern)\b" /dir/file1
grep -r -E -h -o "\b(pattern)\b" /dir/file2
grep -r -E -h -o "\b(pattern)\b" /dir/file3...
```

Comment: Why use `ls` and `xargs` rather than just `/dir/*` as in the question?

Comment: Not sure to understand; « because of the` -n 1` option of xargs » would seem a good answer to your question, but maybe I missed something

Comment: When I asked that question, it still wasn't clear exactly what errors the OP was having. Since it has been clarified that the issue is related to passing too many files to grep at once, then maybe this could help, although it will be quite slow to invoke so many instances of grep. I'm also not sure if there is any advantage to using `ls -1 | xargs` rather than a `for` loop.

Comment: Using `xargs` has the advantage of processing every file as soon as it is generated by the `ls` (or `find`) command. In comparison, the `for` loop must generate the entire list of files, _then_ process it. With memoty and performance impacts it involves. However, I must admit I have not benchmarked.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (but probably not the quickest) way to process all the files would be to do so one by one, using a loop:

```
for file in /dir/*; do
  grep -r -E -h -o '\b(pattern)\b' "$file"
done > outs.txt
```

The overhead of launching all those `grep`s is potentially quite significant, though, so maybe you could use `xargs` to help:

```
find /dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 -n 1000 grep -r -E -h -o '\b(pattern)\b' > outs.txt
```

This uses `find` to produce the list of files in `dir` and passes them safely to `xargs`, separated by a null byte `\0` (a character guaranteed not to be in a filename). `xargs` then passes the files to `grep` in batches of 1000.

(I'm assuming that you have GNU versions of `find` and `xargs` here, for `find -print0` and `xargs -0`)